# react-router (v4) how to go back?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

Trying to figure out how can I go back to the previous page. I am using `[react-router-v4][1]`

This is the code I have configured in my first landing page:

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <Link to="/"><div className="routerStyle"><Glyphicon glyph="home" /></div></Link>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Page1}/>
    <Route path="/Page2" component={Page2}/>
    <Route path="/Page3" component={Page3}/>
  </div>
</Router>
```

In order to forward to subsequent pages, I simply do:

```
this.props.history.push('/Page2');
```

However, how can I go back to previous page? 
Tried few things like mentioned below but no luck:
1. `this.props.history.goBack();`

Gives error:

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.props')

2. `this.context.router.goBack();`

Gives error:

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.context')

3. `this.props.history.push('/');`

Gives error:

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.props')

Posting the `Page1` code here below:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';

class Page1 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleNext = this.handleNext.bind(this);
  }


  handleNext() {
    this.props.history.push('/page2');
  }

  handleBack() {
    this.props.history.push('/');
  }


  /*
   * Main render method of this class
   */
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* some component code */}


        <div className="navigationButtonsLeft">
          <Button onClick={this.handleBack} bsStyle="success">&lt; Back</Button>
        </div>
        <div className="navigationButtonsRight">
          <Button onClick={this.handleNext} bsStyle="success">Next &gt;</Button>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }


export default Page1;
```

Comment: What are the few things, you have tried?

Comment: try 
`this.props.history.goBack();`

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dc2149ec0c63bfc95b71e40c81431e34cfbfeda9/packages/react-router-redux/modules/actions.js#L27

Comment: @VivekDoshi: Added what I tried along with errors I encountered

Comment: @AkshayLokur, will you please post the full code, from where you are trying to execute this.props.history.goBack();?

Comment: @VivekDoshi: Done, please have a look, thanks

Comment: Please check my answer you forgot to this.handleBack = this.handleBack.bind(this);

Comment: @VivekDoshi: Thank you, it worked :)

Comment: Check out @LawrenceEagles answer below for functional components. Easy, and without withRouter

Answer (score 152, accepted):

I think the issue is with binding:

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.goBack = this.goBack.bind(this); // i think you are missing this
}

goBack(){
    this.props.history.goBack();
}

.....

<button onClick={this.goBack}>Go Back</button>
```

As I have assumed before you posted the code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleNext = this.handleNext.bind(this);
    this.handleBack = this.handleBack.bind(this); // you are missing this line
}
```

Comment: doesn't work when browser back button is pressed and in `componentDidUpdate` and `window.onpopstate`?

Answer (score 69):

***UPDATED:***

Now we have hook, so we can do it easily by using [useHistory](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory)

```
const history = useHistory()

const goBack = () => {
  history.goBack()
}

return (
  <button type="button" onClick={goBack}>
    Go back
  </button>
);
```

---

***ORIGINAL POST:***

```
this.props.history.goBack();
```

This is the correct solution for react-router v4

But one thing you should keep in mind is that you need to make sure this.props.history is existed.

That means you need to call this function `this.props.history.goBack();` inside the component that is wrapped by < Route/>

If you call this function in a component that deeper in the component tree, it will not work.

***EDIT:***

If you want to have history object in the component that is deeper in the component tree (which is not wrapped by < Route>), you can do something like this:

```
...
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

class Demo extends Component {
    ...
    // Inside this you can use this.props.history.goBack();
}

export default withRouter(Demo);
```

Comment: So how can it work? How can you go back in history from anywhere?

Comment: @Felipe You can go back from anywhere. I just mean that you need to add this line of code in the Container components in order to get the "history" object, don't use this line of code from Presentational components that is not wrapped by Route (https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0)

Comment: @Felipe: Hi, please check my edited answer. I think it answers your question.

Comment: Thank you for the withRouter edit, that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 19):

For use with React Router v4 and a functional component anywhere in the dom-tree.

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const GoBack = ({ history }) => <img src="./images/back.png" onClick={() => history.goBack()} alt="Go back" />;

export default withRouter(GoBack);
```

Comment: This is a good solution because it does not use a lifecycle method. It is also clearer to me because it denotes what gets passed through, in this case the history object.

Comment: The fat arrow version always looks much cleaner to me, thanks for that.

Answer (score 11):

Each answer here has parts of the total solution. Here's the complete solution that I used to get it to work inside of components deeper than where Route was used:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
```

^ You need that second line to import function and to export component at bottom of page.

```
render() {
  return (
  ...
    <div onClick={() => this.props.history.goBack()}>GO BACK</div>
  )
}
```

^ Required the arrow function vs simply onClick={this.props.history.goBack()}

```
export default withRouter(MyPage)
```

^ wrap your component's name with 'withRouter()'

Answer (score 7):

Here is the cleanest and simplest way you can handle this problem, which also nullifies the probable pitfalls of the `this keyword`. Use functional components:

`import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";`
wrap your `component` or better `App.js` with the `withRouter()` `HOC` this makes `history` to be available "app-wide". wrapping your component only makes `history available for that specific` component``` your choice.

So you have:

1. `export default withRouter(App);`
2. In a Redux environment  `export default withRouter( connect(mapStateToProps, { <!-- your action creators -->})(App), );` you should even be able to user `history` from your action creators this way.

in your `component` do the following:

`import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom";`

`const history = useHistory();  // do this inside the component`

`goBack = () => history.goBack();`

`<btn btn-sm btn-primary onclick={goBack}>Go Back</btn>`

`export default DemoComponent;`

Gottcha `useHistory` is only exported from the latest v5.1 `react-router-dom` so be sure to update the package. However, you should not have to worry.
about the many snags of the `this keyword`.

You can also make this a reusable component to use across your app.

````
function BackButton({ children }) {
  let history = useHistory()
  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={() => history.goBack()}>
      {children}
    </button>
  )
}```
Cheers.
````

Comment: Thanks. But, why is my component not re-rendered when I do a browser back?

Answer (score 5):

Can you provide the code where you use `this.props.history.push('/Page2');`?

Have you tried the goBack() method?

`this.props.history.goBack();`

It's listed here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history

With a live example here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/modal-gallery

Comment: This gives me error, please see updated question above

Comment: Can you also add the code around `this.props.history.push('/Page2');`? If `this.props` is not null there, it should work.

Comment: Nothing really, I just call this on click of Back button in my Component

Answer (score 4):

If using react hooks just do:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
const history = useHistory();
history.go(-1);
```

Answer (score 3):

## UPDATE 2022 w V6

```
navigate(-1)
```

to omit the current page from history:

```
navigate(-1, { replace: true })
```

Comment: thanks- this change from history to navigate repeating over & over again :)

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't use the second one with `replace:true` also here it says that it only takes one param. 
https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate

Comment: @Mahdi-Jafaree I'm not sure what you're referring to. The link you gave doesn't say anything about one param and actually even has the {replace:true} object in the example given.

Comment: cause goBack was too easy...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
this.props.router.goBack()
```

Comment: This gives me error, please see updated question above

Comment: where are you getting your router or history prop from? Make sure you're getting it from your parent component or page (i.e console.log(this.props) on the render function and check that you're printing the router prop in order to be able to use it. Seems to me you don't have router in your component.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
<span onClick={() => this.props.history.goBack()}>Back</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help someone:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as History from 'history';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

interface Props {
  history: History;
}

@withRouter
export default class YourComponent extends React.PureComponent<Props> {

  private onBackClick = (event: React.MouseEvent): void => {
    const { history } = this.props;
    history.goBack();
  };

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help someone.

I was using `history.replace()` to redirect, so when i tried to use `history.goBack()`, i was send to the previous page before the page i was working with.
So i changed the method `history.replace()` to `history.push()` so the history could be saved and i would be able to go back.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if anyone else ran into this problem or may need to see this. But I spent about 3 hours trying to solve this issue:

I wanted to implement a simple goBack() on the click of a button. I thought I was off to a good start because my App.js was already wrapped in the Router and I was importing { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'; ... Since the Router element allows me to assess the history object.

ex:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Splash from './components/Splash';
import Header from './components/Header.js';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Info from './components/Info';
import Timer from './components/Timer';
import Options from './components/Options';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <Route path='/' component={Splash} exact />
      <Route path='/home' component={Info} exact />
      <Route path='/timer' component={Timer} exact />
      <Route path='/options' component={Options} exact />
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}
export default App;
```

BUT the trouble was on my Nav (a child component) module,
I had to 'import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';'
and then force an export with:

```
export default withRouter(Nav);
```

ex:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
class Nav extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <label htmlFor='back'></label>
                <button id='back' onClick={ () => this.props.history.goBack() }>Back</button>
                <label htmlFor='logOut'></label>
                <button id='logOut' ><a href='./'>Log-Out</a>            
</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default withRouter(Nav);
```

in summary, withRouter was created because of a known issue in React where in certain scenarios when inheritance from a router is refused, a forced export is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `history.goBack()` in functional component. Just like this.

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';
const component = () => { 
  const history = useHistory();

  return (
   <button onClick={() => history.goBack()}>Previous</button>
  )
}
```