# React Go back to previous state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

I am new to react using react bootstrap table to show the list of customers and click on the each row should take back to the detail view. I am looking a way to go back to the list view from detail page. How can I achieve that?

Comment: that go back will be on which action? some "go back" button or something else?

Comment: Go back button <=> something like "site list view"

Comment: use `this.props.history.goBack()` in onClick handler, it will navigate to previous page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working Solution:

[react-router (v4) how to go back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46681387/react-router-v4-how-to-go-back)

```js
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.goBack = this.goBack.bind(this); // i think you are missing this
}

goBack(){
    this.props.history.goBack();
}

.....

<button onClick={this.goBack}>Go Back</button>
```