# How to use React Router to go back to previous page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a React website that runs a blog.

The blog has 4 different categories which are sorted in different pages. So Category1 has a page of its own, category2 has a page of its own and so on.

Each blog post has a "back" button. Right now, the back button just hyperlinks the user back to the index page which displays all of the categories. I've tried using React Router to use the previous page the user was using as a hyperlink for the back button so that it doesn't always take them out of the specific category they're looking at.

I can't seem to get anything to work. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is the JS file for the component below:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
import _get from 'lodash/get'
import { Link, graphql } from 'gatsby'
import { ChevronLeft, ChevronRight } from 'react-feather'

import Content from '../components/Content'
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import './SinglePost.css'

export const SinglePostTemplate = ({
  title,
  date,
  body,
  nextPostURL,
  prevPostURL,
  categories = []
}) => (
  <main>
    <article
      className="SinglePost section light"
      itemScope
      itemType="http://schema.org/BlogPosting"
    >
      <div className="container skinny">
        <Link className="SinglePost--BackButton" to="/">
          <ChevronLeft /> BACK
        </Link>
        <div className="SinglePost--Content relative">
          <div className="SinglePost--Meta">
            {date && (
              <time
                className="SinglePost--Meta--Date"
                itemProp="dateCreated pubdate datePublished"
                date={date}
              >
                {date}
              </time>
            )}
            {categories && (
              <Fragment>
                <span>|</span>
                {categories.map((cat, index) => (
                  <span
                    key={cat.category}
                    className="SinglePost--Meta--Category"
                  >
                    {cat.category}
                    {/* Add a comma on all but last category */}
                    {index !== categories.length - 1 ? ',' : ''}
                  </span>
                ))}
              </Fragment>
            )}
          </div>

          {title && (
            <h1 className="SinglePost--Title" itemProp="title">
              {title}
            </h1>
          )}

          <div className="SinglePost--InnerContent">
            <Content source={body} />
          </div>

          <div className="SinglePost--Pagination">
            {prevPostURL && (
              <Link
                className="SinglePost--Pagination--Link prev"
                to={prevPostURL}
              >
                <ChevronLeft /> Previous Post
              </Link>
            )}
            {nextPostURL && (
              <Link
                className="SinglePost--Pagination--Link next"
                to={nextPostURL}
              >
                Next Post <ChevronRight />
              </Link>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </main>
)

// Export Default SinglePost for front-end
const SinglePost = ({ data: { post, allPosts } }) => {
  const thisEdge = allPosts.edges.find(edge => edge.node.id === post.id)
  return (
    <Layout
      meta={post.frontmatter.meta || false}
      title={post.frontmatter.title || false}
    >
      <SinglePostTemplate
        {...post}
        {...post.frontmatter}
        body={post.html}
        nextPostURL={_get(thisEdge, 'next.fields.slug')}
        prevPostURL={_get(thisEdge, 'previous.fields.slug')}
      />
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default SinglePost

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  ## Query for SinglePost data
  ## Use GraphiQL interface (http://localhost:8000/___graphql)
  ## $id is processed via gatsby-node.js
  ## query name must be unique to this file
  query SinglePost($id: String!) {
    post: markdownRemark(id: { eq: $id }) {
      ...Meta
      html
      id
      frontmatter {
        title
        template
        subtitle
        date(formatString: "MMMM Do, YYYY")
        categories {
          category
        }
      }
    }
    allPosts: allMarkdownRemark(
      filter: { fields: { contentType: { eq: "posts" } } }
      sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date] }
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
        }
        next {
          fields {
            slug
          }
          frontmatter {
            title
          }
        }
        previous {
          fields {
            slug
          }
          frontmatter {
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react-router (v4) how to go back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46681387/react-router-v4-how-to-go-back)

Answer (score 1):

First, [get a history object](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory):

```
let history = useHistory();
```

Then add a click handler to the button and call [`history.goBack()`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/history).

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Link to={-1}>go back</Link>
```

I used this in v6 and it's working well